# Custom validation on Model based on which Rest api is getting called

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot

I have to develop multiple apis for `PUT`, `POST`, `PATCH` in which request consists of same model. For `PUT` and `POST` I need to put validation on all the fields while for `PATCH` validation should only work for few fields which are coming in request. I am using JSON based validation. Is there a way I can define that for Patch validation works only when data is sent but for post and put validation has to work always. So for below model `BusinessDetails`, validation on all fields should work for `POST` and `PUT` api and For `PATCH` whatever data comes validation should work for that.

```
    public class BusinessDetails{
        @JsonProperty("business_name")
        @NotBlank()
        private String businessName;

        @JsonProperty("business_city")
        @NotBlank()
        private String businessCity;

        @JsonProperty("business_num")
        @NotBlank()
        @Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]+$")
        private String businessNumber;
    }
```

My goal is to avoid separate model for same request, redundant code and also wants validation do be done at Request level rather than doing the same manually later on. 
    If there is any other better solution do so that also I will take into consideration.

Comment: get rid of @Valid on your PATCH request handler

Comment: Will be doing same  Thanks